# FullCalendar within JquerySteps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, jquery-steps

I'm currently setting up a stepped form that includes an implementation of FullCalendar to do some nice datepicking around existing events.

I've ran into some difficulty and when including a FullCalendar within a Steps div, the calendar will render, but the buttons (next / previous month) will not work, and events such as the "selected" event when clicking a date do not fire.

I've boiled this down to a simple replication on jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/rihovapezi/1/edit?html,output

I can also test and see that fullcalendar works (can be interacted with) when outside of the steps div: http://jsbin.com/mezavisata/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just move the line `$("#wizard").steps();` before  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar`

[**JSbin**](http://jsbin.com/geveyajitu/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Awesome! I found that the calendar did not render if it was not on the first step, but adding in 

if (currentIndex === 4) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
                }


and we're away! Thanks!